# WinXP Hangs After Loading Mup.sys

Tags: windows-xp, chkdsk, mup.sys

Hardware:

- Dell Dimension 2400
- 2x 80Gb HHD (Drives C and E)

Booting normally results in the system hanging at the Windows loading screen where the blue dots pass by. I booted into Safe Mode and ran `chkdsk c:/r` then typed Y to affirm that I would like to run it on the next boot.

I rebooted the machine and then it stayed on the Windows loading screen for a bit. I turned it off (probably a bad idea in hindsight) and attempted to boot into Safe Mode again by hitting F8 until the appropriate menu appeared. The last driver to be loaded before seeming to hang again is `Mup.sys`. I understand that `Mup.sys` is probably not the issue, but whatever is loaded after it.

I read [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-system/xp-hangs-at-mupsys-on-startup/97c6550f-a1ef-45bb-9666-b773bacfdac0?msgId=0dcf264c-188c-4162-af84-1386ea46bbb6) that `chkdsk` might be running after all but I have no reason to believe so other than the fact that the hard drive(s) seem to be working and the HDD light is solid green with no flickering.

I'm wondering if I should try using a restore point? I don't want to reboot again if `chkdsk` is indeed running.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I rebooted normally and let it set overnight. `chkdsk` is now 30 percent through stage 4 of 5.

Comment: CHKDSK will display if it is running. Mup.sys is simply the last file to load before it tries to load the Windows environment. Do you have any external devices plugged in, like USB? That can impact boot up times.

Comment: There is a PS/2 mouse and a USB keyboard attached.

Comment: That's ok then. I was thinking more along the lines of an external drive.

Comment: Any thoughts regarding trying to use a restore point?